# How to randomly select new elements from an expandig list of elements for each user?

Tags: database, algorithm, feed, recommendation-engine, bloom-filter

I have a list of content with different categories and also with creation time and possibly expiration time which is changing over time (new items are added to it), I also have many users with different preferences.
Now what i want to do is showing this users new content each time they ask one, without duplication but also with some degree of randomness.
Obviously I can not store all of the shown contents to a user and each time check the whole set.
One possible solution is to use some clusters and assign each user to a cluster, and store some data for each cluster, but I think there is a better way.

edit: OK, after asking the same question from my colleagues, they suggested "Bloom Filters", does anyone agree with them?

Answer (score 0):

For each user, have a priority queue of items to show. Every time an item is created, insert it into every interested user's priority queue with a randomized priority.  When the user looks at it, remove the top item from the priority queue until you find one that is not expired.  All per user operations will have time `O(log(n))` which should be acceptable.

Comment: This is a good solution for limited number of users or content, but I have millions of users, millions of content (with thousands of categories) and each user has tens of interests; I think your solution's disk overhead is too much, is it not?

Comment: What you do in that case is map users to machines, and each machine keeps track of what it needs to.  There are also optimizations around inserting things in the per user priority queue only at the last minute.  But in the end you're trying to solve the same infrastructure problem that Twitter has, and it is going to be hard for the same reasons that it is for them.